# ibgtop function glibtop_get_cpu() information breaks down if a processor is disabled

Tags: linux

I am pretty much a first timer at this so please feel free to tell where I have not followed correct procedure. I will do better next time..

My claim: libgtop function glibtop_get_cpu() information breaks down if a processor is disabled.

My environment: I have disabled processor #1 (0,1,2,3) for a hardware issue I have with a motherboard. Since that time, and presumably as a result, gnome-system-monitor now reports the machine as having 3 cpus (which is correct) and calls them CPU1, CPU2 and CPU3 (not wild about the labels used here but we can discuss that another time). The more important problem is that the CPU values for CPU2 and CPU3 are always zero. When I compare the CPU of gnome-system-monitor to ‘top’ (using the ‘1’ key to get individual processors), they don’t match. When I say don’t match, ‘top’ values are non-zero, while gnome-system-monitor values are zero.

‘top’ reports %Cpu0, 2 and 3. No sign of CPU 1. More important, the numeric values for these labels are non-zero. When I use the ‘stress’ command, the values move around as expected. ‘top’ indicates the individual processors are at 100% while gnome-system-monitor says 0.

Summary so far: ‘top’ gives plausible figures for CPU while gnome-system-monitor does not. On my system, I have disabled CPU 1 (0 index) and see that CPU2 (1 index) and CPU3 (1 index) have zero CPU.

I have been reading and modifying the code in gnome-system-monitor to explore where these values are coming from and I have determined that there is nothing ‘wrong’ with gnome-system-monitor program per se; at least as far as the numeric values for CPU are concerned. This is because the data gnome-system-monitor uses is coming from libgtop library and specifically the glibtop_get_cpu() function. The resulting data returned by glibtop_get_cpu() is zero for all indexes of 1 (0 index – this is in the C++ code) or greater.

It seems to me, I need to see how glibtop_get_cpu() works, but I have had no luck finding the source to glibtop_get_cpu(). What should I do next? The library I am using is 2.38.0-2ubuntu0.18.04.1 … on Ubuntu 18.04.1. Happy to try any suggestions. I probably won’t know how to do what you suggest, but I can learn.

Should I raise a bug? I would like to go deeper than this on the first pass if possible. I was hoping to  look at the problem and propose a fix but at the moment, I am stuck.

**Edit!** (improvements suggested to the original question)

Incorrect output:

```
# echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online // bring all cpu online for the base case

$ ./test_get_cpu
glibtop_sysinfo()->ncpu is 4
xcpu_total[0] is 485898
xcpu_total[1] is 1532
xcpu_total[2] is 484263
xcpu_total[3] is 487052
$

# echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online // take cpu1 offline again

$ ./test_get_cpu
glibtop_sysinfo()->ncpu is 3        // ncpu is correct
xcpu_total[0] is 501416
$

# echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online  // bring cpu1 online
# echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/online      // … and take cpu2 offline

$ ./test_get_cpu
glibtop_sysinfo()->ncpu is 3
xcpu_total[0] is 508264
xcpu_total[1] is 5416
$
```

Interpretation: As anticipated, taking 'cpu2' offline means we can't see 'cpu3' in the glibtop_get_cpu() result. By induction, (risky) I think that it we take 'cpu' offline, we will not get any statistics for all 'cpu' and higher.

That is my evidence for something wrong with glibtop_get_cpu().

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <glibtop/cpu.h>
#include <glibtop/sysinfo.h>

main() {
  const glibtop_sysinfo * sysinfo = glibtop_get_sysinfo();
  glibtop_cpu cpu;
  glibtop_get_cpu(&cpu);
  cout << "glibtop_sysinfo()->ncpu is " << sysinfo->ncpu << endl;
  //for (int i=0;i<sysinfo->ncpu;++i) { // e.g. ncpu might be 3 if one processor disabled on a quad core
  for (int i=0;i<GLIBTOP_NCPU;++i) { // Alternatively, look through 1024 slots
    if (cpu.xcpu_total[i] != 0) {
      cout << "xcpu_total[" << i << "] is " << cpu.xcpu_total[i] << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Eight paragraphs to ask if you should raise a bug report? Show your code, show the incorrect output and ask a real question... And look into a modern library like [`hwloc`](https://github.com/open-mpi/hwloc).

Comment: @jww Thanks for those kind and welcoming words to Stackoverflow. I have updated the question in an attempt to correct some of my terrible oversights in my first post. I will have a look into hwloc in the near future. Thanks for that suggestion. I will also have to look at 'top' and see how it works 'cause I like the way it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the code I was looking for @ https://github.com/GNOME/libgtop

Sorry to have wasted anyone's time. I don't know precisely how the above code works. For example I don't know how/if/where glibtop_get_cpu_l() is defined but I can see enough in the code to realize that as the code stands it looks at /proc/stat and if a specific "cpu" isn't found then that is a 'warning' and is logged somewhere (don't now where) and the rest of the cpu's are skipped. I will do more work on this in my own time.